# Wordpress: Turn off display of posts until filter button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

(This is an extension of a series of questions I have asked previously as I'm going through the process of learning how to work with Wordpress)

I'm using a small javascript to turn on and off the display of posts on a page, depending on the posts respective category. The script enables a group of filter buttons at the top of the page to switch between displaying posts that belong to a certain category.

Now I would like to change the page's code so that upon loading the page for the first time (i.e. before any of the filter buttons have been clicked) there is no content/posts being displayed at all. Right now when accessing the page, all posts which belong to the parent category of the sub-categories (which the buttons allow to filter) are being displayed.

How do I have to change the site to do so?

An online version of the site can be visited here: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/studierende/

Here's the site's code along with the javascript of the filter-button at the bottom:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper-offset-fix wrapper-studierende">
<div class="projekte content">

    <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-stud-sose17">SoSe 2017</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-stud-wise1617">WiSe 2016/17</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-wise-201415">SoSe 2016 </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-14">WiSe 2015/16</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-14">SoSe 2015 </button>
        <button class="projekt-btn btn" id="category-sose-14">WiSe 2014/15</button>    
    </div>

    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('full');
            } ?> 

    <?php the_content(); ?>

            </a>
        <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);
        $('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin this by first hiding all the posts. **One way** to do this would be add a CSS style

```
.projekte .post {display:none;}
```

Looking at your codes, rest should just work out by itself. I would however swap these lines so that the posts are removed before the new ones are added like this:

```
$('.projekte > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly. But I don't understand what you mean to do by swapping the two lines, I did so, but it didn't change the way the posts are loading.

Comment: for me on firefox browser, there was a flicker, when the new post would load and before the old post was removed from view, so I suggested removing the old post before showing the new one.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, I see the flicker on the Chrome browser as well. But swapping the two lines didn't change it unfortunately.

Comment: Check out the current version: http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/studierende/ There I have swapped the lines